# Problems after Relocated JAVA Libraries to Tomcat Lib folder

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat

I have a problem with my project. I uploaded all my libraries to Tomcat Lib folder, and error occurred.

org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: /hibernate.cfg.xml
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1494)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:990)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.doConfigure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1428)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:972)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1414)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:966)
    at com.billing.util.HibernateUtil.getInitializedConfiguration(HibernateUtil.java:126)
    at com.billing.util.HibernateUtil.getSession(HibernateUtil.java:132)
    at com.billing.util.HibernateUtil.beginTransaction(HibernateUtil.java:153)
    at dscv2.login.userCtrl.UserLogin.processRequest(UserLogin.java:62)
    at dscv2.login.loginCtrlServlet.processRequest(loginCtrlServlet.java:48)
    at dscv2.login.loginCtrlServlet.doPost(loginCtrlServlet.java:121)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory Nested exception: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:1484)
    ... 27 more

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't be putting stuff in the Tomcat /lib directory except, as noted by Mike Baranczak below, JDBC driver JARs.  (And even that is true only for Tomcat 6.x and higher.  It used to be that those would go in your WEB-INF/lib as well.)

Learn how to create a proper WAR and deploy it to the /webapps directory.

Comment: Background explanation: your classpath is polluted with multiple different versioned DOM4J JAR files. Solution is indeed to not tamper the classpath with libraries at wrong places :)

Comment: There are some things that do need to be in Tomcat's lib directory, like database drivers when you're using container-managed connections. But those are the exceptions.

Comment: Thank you for the correction, Michael.  I've added it to my answer.